# Referening chunked Dataframe - Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have broken a large dataframe into small chunks. I am now trying to pass the data from these chunks into a loop but I am not sure how to call each of these chunked dataframes.

I have broken the Dataframe into 4 chunks as shown below. But I am not sure how to call each of these chunked Dataframe and pass them in a loop

```
n = 4
chunks = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

- you describe a **bigdf** that is *chunked* into a list of data frames.  I have simulated this
- if you want a **list comprehension** of rows in subset of data frame **list** it's a simple case of effectively looping over both lists

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
bigdf = pd.DataFrame({"chunk":np.random.choice(range(10),1000),"value":np.random.uniform(2,3,1000)})
# list of dataframes that are chunks from bigdf
df = [bigdf.loc[bigdf["chunk"].eq(i)] for i in range(10)]
n = 4
# list comprehension of required chucks and array of each row in chunk
[v for chunk in range(n) for v in df[chunk].values ]
```